# ADAL v3 - How to properly get rid of refresh token code?

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-sdk-.net

In ADAL v2, we were doing this:

```
// Common parameter:
_clientCredential = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, certificate);

// Get the token for the first time:
var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(accessToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", userName);
_authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, _clientCredential, userAssertion);

// Refresh the token (when needed):
_authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync(authResult.RefreshToken, _clientCredential);
```

Note that in order to refresh the token, we only need the previous authentication result and the common client credential (`_authResult` and `_clientCredential`). **This is very convenient.**

ADAL v3 lacks AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync, and [here is the explanation](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/13/adal-3-didnt-return-refresh-tokens-for-5-months-and-nobody-noticed/). But that doesn't say, in concrete terms, what kind of change is needed.

Do we have to replay the first AcquireTokenAsync (and therefore keep `resource`, `accessToken` and `userName` stored somewhere in the program state)?

Or is there some way of getting an up-to-date token with only the common elements (`_authResult` and `_clientCredential`)?

Comment: AcquireTokenSilentAsync()? ;)

Comment: @juunas All overloads of `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` require `resource`. Is there a way to extract the `resource` from the `AuthenticationResult`?

Comment: Even if I specify the `resource` again, I get the error `multiple_matching_tokens_detected`, which means I have to repeat the `username` as well... :-(

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism to use a refresh token is now provided by AcquireTokenSilentAsync. See [AcquireTokenSilentAsync using a cached token using a cached token](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token) for patterns to use this.

Are you utilizing the [ADAL token Cache] (http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/01/getting-acquainted-with-adals-token-cache/)? It saves you from managing the underlying implementation details of using refresh tokens in your code and the issue you are facing.

Comment: I am using token cache. The problem of `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` is that it forces me to store `resource` and `username`. The convenience of just refreshing a token, without knowledge of all input parameters, was removed in ADAL v3.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach for the on-behalf-of flow in ADAL 3.x is to use:

```
try
{
 result = await ac.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, clientId);
}
catch (AdalException adalException)
{
 if (adalException.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently ||
     adalException.ErrorCode == AdalError.InteractionRequired)
 {
  result = await ac. AcquireTokenAsync (resource, clientCredentials, userAssertion);
 }
}
```

For more details see https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Service-to-service-calls-on-behalf-of-the-user

Note that there are scenarios where you could have cached a refresh token acquired with ADAL.NET v2.x, and to help migrating from ADAL 2.x to MSAL.NET, we plan to re-introduce the AcquireTokenByRefreshToken in MSAL.NET (but not in ADAL 4.x)

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work. We attempted that, but sometimes we get the error `multiple_matching_tokens_detected`.